# В карточке товара перестал отображаться выбор цвета. Где копать?

Tags: php, javascript, css, opencart

Делаю адаптивку на сайте [кресломешок](http://xn--e1aancdgncml5f.xn--j1amh/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=222), в карточке товара есть возможность выбирать цвет товара, она происходит, но пропала запись самого выбраного цвета после Выберите цвет [image: введите сюда описание изображения], до процедуры адаптации карточки товара эта запись отображалась при выборе цвета. Как исправить эту оплошность, помогите, голова идет оборотом не могу найти скрипт который за это отвечает. Спасибо.

UPD: уточняю свой вопрос: выбор цвета работает, но не отображается запись выбранного цвета (как на скрине), js я не менял, только разметка и стили;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На странице скрипт

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
              $('input.action').removeClass('action');
              $(this).addClass('action');
              $(this).find('input[type=radio]').checked = true;
            });
```

Вы пытаетесь внутри элемента `input` найти `input` с типом `radio` и поставить атрибут `checked`. Исправьте.

Событие не нужно на все `input` элементы ставить, берите в контексте выбора цвета

```
$('.item_info .option input[type="radio"]')
```

Comment: По поводу отладки если не знаете где искать: в Chrome жмем F12, выбираем элемент у которого предположим меняется атрибут при нажатии, жмем правой кнопкой мыши, выбираем `Break on...` -> `Attributes Modifications` и выполняем действие которое меняет атрибут. Далее работаем с отладкой после того как активирован брекпоинт.

Comment: то есть $(this).find('input[type=radio]').checked = true; меняем на $('.item_info .option input[type="radio"]').checked = true;

Comment: нет. достаточно `$(this).prop('checked', true)`. Можно вообще без JS обойтись, обернуть  радиокнопку в элемент `label` и в css по состоянию :checked повесить нужный стиль

Comment: благодарю за такой полезный совет и комментарий

Comment: к сожалению замена на $(this).prop('checked', true) результата не дала

Comment: дело в том что я вообще js тут не писал и соответственно при адаптивке не трогал, менялась только разметка и стили